# Tinymce doesn't save content on specified selector

Tags: javascript, tinymce

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "#description",
theme : 'advanced',
plugins : 'safari,inlinepopups,autosave,preview,paste,spellchecker,tabfocus,wordcount',
theme_advanced_styles : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3;Table Row=tableRow1;Normal=content"
});
```

It displays tinymce editor.If I change/add some content and click on form submit button it shows an alert message like `You have unsaved changes that will be lost if you decided to continue.`

Comment: Can you provide an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Here is jsfiddle exmaple http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/12349/

Comment: This appears to just instantiate the plugin, can you set up the page so that it recreates the error you are getting when you click on a form submit button as your initially stated?

Comment: Updated above jsfiddle example  with form and save button . Please have a look.